# SelectProps of MUI/Joy can't be used correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

> Generic type 'SelectProps' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

```
import "./Select.styles.scss";
// import { Select as JoySelect, SelectProps } from "@mui/material";
import JoySelect from "@mui/joy/Select";
import { SelectProps } from "@mui/joy";
import { ArrowDown2 } from "iconsax-react";
const Select = (props: SelectProps) => {
  const required_star =
    props?.required === true ? <span className="requiredStar">*</span> : "";
  console.log(props.title, props.value);
  return (
    <div className="select-container">
      <p className="title">
        {props?.title} {required_star}
      </p>
      <JoySelect
        {...props}
        fullWidth
        indicator={<ArrowDown2 size={18} color="#90A0B7" />}
        sx={{
          height: 40,
          borderColor: "#334D6E",
          padding: "0px 10px",
          width: "100%",
        }}
        // placeholder="Select"
        placeholder={`Select ${props.title}`}
        variant="outlined"
        // value={props.value}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

// Some default props
Select.defaultProps = {
  size: "small",
  fullWidth: true,
};

export default Select;
```

I was trying to import it from Mui but there are some missing styling props such as placeholder. Now, I'm trying to import it from Joy I'm getting the error: Generic type 'SelectProps' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.